# Every primitive matrix is irreducible?

Tags: matrices

$A$ is reducible if there is some permutation matrix $P$ such that
$$ PAP^T = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
B & C \\ 
O & D \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

And, if $A^k > O$ for some k, then $A$ is called primitive.

Then, how can I show that every primitive matrix is irreducible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of primitive matrix is wrong. A primitive matrix is a *nonnegative* matrix $A$ such that $A^k>0$ for some *natural integer* $k$. You cannot remove the nonnegativity requirement on $A$ and the positivity requirement on $k$.

If $A$ is reducible, then it is, by definition, permutation-similar to a block upper triangular matrix $M$. Since $M^k$ is block upper triangular for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it always contains a zero block. Yet $M^k$ is permutation-similar to $A^k$. So, $A^k$ always contains a zero entry and hence it is not primitive.

Comment: Oh your 'B' is not same with the B in the problem. I seriously worried for nothing. Thank you!

Comment: @plhn Uhh, my bad. I've changed the symbol now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

An easier way (IMO) to understand that every non-negative primitive matrix $A$ is also irreducible is by simply examining the definitions (some of them might be considered as alternative - but equivalent - definitions):

Let $A$ be a non-negative matrix.

1. $A$ is **primitive** if the following holds:

   $\exists k \forall (i,j) : A^k_{ij} > 0$
2. $A$ is **irreducible** if the following holds:

   $\forall (i,j) \exists k : A^k_{ij} > 0$

Notice the slight difference between the 2 definitions - for (2) it means that every pair $(i,j)$ has its own value of $k$ (or perhaps it's better to denote it as a function: $k(i,j)$), while in (1) it's the same value of $k$ for all the $(i,j)$ pairs. Thus, (1) is clearly a particular case of (2), and therefore, if a non-negative matrix is primitive, then it's also irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

For n ≥ 2, an n × n non-negative matrix $A$ is
irreducible if $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_k$ is positive matrix.

For n ≥ 2, an n × n non-negative matrix A is
primitive if there exists $k\in N$ such that  $A_k$ is positive matrix.

According to the definition, we can get example:
$A=[0,1;1,0]$, with $spec(A)=\{1,-1\}$ and eigenvector are $[1,0]^T, [0,1]^T$. So diagonalization is :
$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{matrix} \right]=D=Q^{-1}AQ$
Look at this! the sum of A^k (from k=1 to n-1) is positive definitely. But does it primitive? No$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}A^k=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}QD^kQ^{-1}$, but A is primitive if the following holds: $∃k,∀(i,j):A_{ij}^k>0$ . Obviously can we say A is primitive when k approaching infty?

So the irreducible matrix may not be the primitive matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A nonnegative, irreducible matrix is called *primitive* if and only if its maximal modulus eigenvalue is simple (algebraic and geometric multiplicities both equal to one). See Definition 8.5.0 in Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson. A nonnegative, irreducible matrix is primitive if and only if it is aperiodic (ibid. Theorem 8.5.3).  According to this source, we wouldn't ever call a reducible matrix primitive. Though a reducible matrix can still have a simple maximal modulus eigenvalue, e.g. the zero matrix with a lone positive number at one location in the diagonal.

So we can see that a nonnegative matrix being **primitive** is the same thing as being **irreducible and aperiodic**.